# DIP not displaying when doc template saved on SP

Tags: 2013, content-type, document-template, dip

I have saved a document template and a Document Information Panel into a templates library in SharePoint 2013. If I associate the document template using a url to a content type (eg. `http://pathto/Template/docTemplate.docx`) the DIP is not displayed in Word.

However if I 'Upload a new document template' using the same file then the DIP is displayed.

Is there any reason why using a URL for a doc template will fail to display the DIP?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have site available at the moment, so I can't test this. But when you set the document template by URL, does the DIP url option update under "Document Information Panel settings"? If not, perhaps you need to manually set this to the url of the DIP file?

I'm sorry for posting this as an answer. But I can't make comments as I don't have the required reputation.